# iReport presenting data horizontally back

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Using iReports, is there a way to display the data where it's going back and forth and pulling the data from one SQL statement?

Where an SQL query returned the following records

```
a0
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
```

The report would be filled as follows ...

```
 a0 a1
 a2 a3
 a4 a5
```

Normally I wouldn't have a problem doing a table, but I have to replicate someone's "application."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, iReports allows you to fill your report so that the **data is presented horizontally** as you require in your question.

You can also specify how many columns you present in your report.

1. In the Report Inspector, right click on the report and select
   **Properties**
2. In the Properties Dialog,

   - Click on the number beside **Columns**, enter **2**.
   - Click on **Print Order**, select **Horizontal**
   - Click on **Close**
   - Press <kbd>CTRL ALT PgDn</kbd> to preview your report

Comment: I don´t have iReport at hands right now but it should be a way easier. There should be an element which you can place in your report which skips to the next result-row. I´m sure I´ve read about this in the documentation.

Comment: Well, like a lot of things in iReports it's not that hard when you know how, carrying out the above steps takes seconds but I agree that finding out how to get something done in iReports can be a bit of a drawn out treasure hunt. imho this is because iReports is a essentially a JRXML file producer and as such you sometimes need to know that your way around that XML inorder to figure out the capabilities of the iReports UI.

Comment: After testing this method, this method works for what I need. Thank you for this response. I had been digging for quite a while and still didn't come up with an answer.

Comment: It's a pleasure, glad it was what you needed. It wasn't easy to find but the more you hunt around with iReports the easier it gets. Check the JasperReport samples to see what it possible, their JRXML and work it back from the JRXML to iReports.